# how do i change player 1 text when i press 1, 2, 3 ? to player has chosen

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

so im trying to make it when player 1 can choose it changes it text when the player has chosen 1, 2, 3 but its not really working

this is part of my html

and it is about player one that i gave a id of choose1

```
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-8">
                <div class="jumbotron multiGame">
                    <h2 id="choose1">Player 1 Selected: <span style="color: #eee;" id="player1"></span></h2>
                    <h2>Player 2 selected <span id="player2"></span></h2>
                    <h2 id="roundScore"></h2>
                    <div class="messageBox"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

this is my javascript its only part of the code btw.

```
    document.onkeyup = function(event) {
        console.log($(".lock").text());
        console.log($(".round").text());
        if($(".lock").text() === $(".round").text()){
            switch(event.key){
                case '1':
                    userText.textContent = 'rock';
                break;
                case '2':
                    userText.textContent = 'paper';
                break;
                case '3':
                    userText.textContent = 'scissors';
                break;
            }
            var player1selection = document.getElementById("player1").innerText
            if(event.key ===  '1' || '2' || '3'){
                userSelection('player2');
                var player2selection = document.getElementById("player2").innerText;
                turn[0] = player1selection;
                turn[1] = player2selection;
                bestOfThree.push(turn);
                console.log(turn);
                score(player1selection, player2selection);
                trackScore();
                console.log();
                if(!(turn[0] === "") && !(turn[1] === "")){
                    console.log('reset');
                    var nextRound = $(".lock").text(Number($(".lock").text()) + 1);
                    $(".messageBox").append("<button class='reset' >Start the next round?</button>");
                    reset();
                }
            } 
        }  
    }
};
```

im trying to make it when the player1 presses 1 2 or 3 it changes the text from Player 1 Selected: to player one has chosen. but im not sure what to do

Comment: this is javascript not java related question

Comment: sorry i changed it

Comment: Please trim down your code to the essence. We don't know what `score`, `trackScore`, ".lock", ".round", `bestOfThree`, `turn`, ...etc is, and it is probably not relevant to your problem either. Note that the `if` condition `event.key ===  '1' || '2' || '3'` is always true, no matter what `event.key` is. If you use a debugger, inspecting variables, setting breakpoints, you can find this out yourself.